# How to find the number of databases in a SQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was wondering how I can find the number of databases in a SQL server. Thanks.

Comment: `SQL Server` != [tag:mysql] -- Which is it?

Comment: The server is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which DBMS you're referring to, so I'll cover both:

**MySQL**

From root, execute the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   information_schema.SCHEMATA
```

You can further distill it *(if you want to avoid system tables)* by adding:

```
WHERE  schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')
```

**[Microsoft] SQL Server**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   sys.databases
```